# Getting ECMAScript Client OM Intellisense to work in ASCX/JS

Tags: visual-studio, client-object-model, application-pages, visual-web-part

I can't for the life of me get intellisense working for the Client OM. It seems to work on another box I have tried so I'm wondering if I have found some kind of bug/configuration issue.

I have tried all the methods in the [official MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798328.aspx) and [COB's post](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/12/sp2010-ajax-part-5-enable-intellisense.html) with no luck. Visual Studio indicates it is 'Updating JScript Intellisense' but it just doesn't work. I have tried this in a Visual Web Part, Application Page and js file.

My environment is as follows -

- VS2010 SP1
- VS2011 Ultimate Beta
- Resharper

I also have the CKSDev tools installed, CAML.net intellisense and a few other extensions.

I'm wondering if its something to do with me having VS2011 installed. Has anyone else had similar issues? I would really like to get ECMAScript intellisense working as it would be massively handy!

Cheers

Alex

Comment: Just an update - it works in VS2011 :S

Comment: I don't think its because of VS11. I have also got both installed on my dev machine and the intellisense works well in VS2010

Comment: I've just figured it out - its resharper! once I turned off resharper's intellisense it started working :-)

Answer (score 1):

There could be two issues other than the Re sharper, this has happened with my Dev team as well.

We implemented the following two solutions

[Missing Intellisense and Document for VS 2010](http://rohankondvilkar.blogspot.com/2012/03/missing-intellisense-and-document.html)

[Intellisense for ECMA Scripting in VS 2010](http://rohankondvilkar.blogspot.com/2012/03/sharepoint-2010-client-side-ecma-script.html)

Hope this will help you work with the Resharper as well.

Regards,

HammerGuy

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys - it's caused by Resharper. Once I turned off the option to use Resharper's intellisense over VS's it started working :-)